# Sorting events based on members in fullCalender

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I am using a public google calendar where various users create events via my application and can view them. However upon using fullCalender I am fetching all the events together(All users can view all the events, however I want so that user can only view the events he/she is a part of). Is there a way to fetch events purely based on the group members in the event.